# Ovi map for iphone

Tags: iphone, dictionary

Hello i want to know is there any API for ovi map for iphone ?

Comment: Ovi map which is for nokia Phone..

Comment: I'm guessing that since it's a Nokia-provided service, they're not going to want other devices, like iPhones, to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, according to their site.

You can use their javascript based API

check that http://api.maps.ovi.com/devguide/overview.html